# How to replace whole string which matches regex in a pandas series

Tags: python, regex, pandas

When I try to replace a group of strings according to my regex in pandas series the replacement happens only for the part of string. I want the whole string to be replaced with my replacement text.
I've attached the images for reference.
If someone could help, it will be really helpful

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `I've attached the images for reference` ... we can't see any images here.

Comment: Sorry I've added images now.. please look into it now

Comment: Can't you just replace by the cell value, i.e.: `df1.Gender[~df1.Gender.isin(['Man, Woman')] = 'Others'`?

Comment: If you want to use regex, try this. `df1['Gender'] = df1['Gender'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'^(Man)','Others', str(x)))`

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this if you not that familiar with regex:

```
df.loc[~df['Gender'].isin(['Man', 'Woman']), 'Gender'] = 'Other'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df1['Gender'].str.replace(r'(Man)|(Woman)', 'Others')
```

If something is inside squre brackets '[  ]', then each of the characters are mapped separately.
Go to [python regex documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for more details.

> [ ] Used to indicate a set of characters. In a set:
>
> Characters can be listed individually, e.g. [amk] will match 'a', 'm',
> or 'k'.

Comment: Sir I want to replace text different from "man" or "woman" with others. What could be the expression. Thanks in advance